# Defining the Context Free Grammar for a function's signature

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I am learning about Context Free Grammars for a Compilers course I'm attending to. I was trying to define a Grammar for function's signatures. Examples would be:

```
int a
int b, int c
Object a, Object d
...
```

The closest I could achieve to something like that was:

```
Params -> Params, Param
       |  Param
       |  lambda

Param -> paramType paramName
```

Yet this isn't what I want. This grammar allows incorrect string as `, int a`. I've been here for a while and I can't think of a better way to get to a correct grammar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what we want is `(Param,)* Param | lambda`, so how do that in production rules? Well we can introduce another rule for `(Param,)*`, like this:

```
ParamCommas -> Param, ParamCommas
            |  lambda
```

Then we can use it in `Params` like this:

```
Params -> ParamCommas Param
       |  lambda
```

Note that we don't need an extra rule for a single `Param` as `ParamCommas` can already be `lambda`.

Comment: That's a nice try. Yet, it suffers from a problem. It accepts strings like "int a int b". This ocurrs when ParamCommas is lambda. The problem is allowing ParamCommas to be lambda.

Comment: @devoured: I don't see it. Which derivations do you use to get "int a int b"? ParamCommas will either by lambda or a sequence of Params separated by and ending with a comma. So the rule `ParamCommas Param` either gives you just `Param` (if `ParamCommas` is lambda) or multiple params separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing this:

```
Param-> AB|lambda
A-> param
B->','paramB|lambda
```